# How do you combine 2 php iterations?

Tags: php, iteration

Can somebody help me combine these 2 iterations, to allow both array items to display on my webpage? What I'm trying to do is to display the videoURL and the corresponding GroupName in my webpage.

**First:**

```
try
{
 $sql = 'SELECT URL from videoclip';
 $result = $pdo->query($sql);

}
catch (PDOException $e)

{
 $error ='Error fetching videos:'.$e->getMessage();
 include'error.html.php';
 exit();
}

while ($row = $result->fetch())
{
  $URLS[] = $row['URL'];
}

include 'index.html.php';
```

**Second:**

```
try
{
  $sql = 'SELECT GroupName from videoclip';
  $result = $pdo->query($sql);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
 $error ='unable to fecth data:'.$e->getMessage();
 include'error.html.php';
 exit();
}

while ($row = $result->fetch())
{
  $GroupNames[] = $row['GroupName'];
}
include 'index.html.php';
```

Comment: `SELECT URL , GroupName  from videoclip` ???? is all you need

Comment: How about you learn PHP and then ask us to what you could do yourself in 2 seconds.

Comment: @AlexLunix: How about you speak nicely to a new user, and not forget you were in his state possibly not so long ago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just combine your query and then build a multidimensional array to pass to `index.html.php`

```
try
{
  $sql = "SELECT URL, GroupName FROM videoclip";
  $result = $pdo->query($sql);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  $error = 'unable to fetch data: '.$e->getMessage();
  include'error.html.php';
  exit();
}
$URLS = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch())
{
  $URLS[] = array('URL' => $row['URL'], 'GroupName' => $row['GroupName'] );
}

include 'index.html.php';
```

Comment: Thanks , i got it running with this Php code to display URL AND GroupName <li>
                                <?php echo ($URL['URL']) ; ?>
                         
                            <h3 class="Group_title">
                                <?php echo ($URL['GroupName']) ; ?>
                            </h3>

                            <h5 class="Music_title">
                                <?php echo ($URL['VideoTITLE']) ; ?>
                            </h5>



                        </li>